# Nextflow and Preemptible Machines in Google Life Sciences

Tags: nextflow

Consider a nextflow workflow that uses the Google Life Sciences API and uses preemptible machines. The config might look like this:

```
google {
    project = "cool-name"
    region = "cool-region"
    
    lifeSciences {
        bootDiskSize = "200 GB"
        preemptible = True
    }
}
```

Let's say you have only a single process and this process has the directive `maxRetries = 5`. After five retries (=after the 6th time), the process will be considered failed.

Is it somehow possible to specify in nextflow that after a certain number of retries were unsuccessful, that nextflow should request a non-preemptible machine instead and continue retrying a couple more times?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change [executors](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#scope-executor) or change executor config using an [errorStrategy](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#errorstrategy), AFAIK. I think it would be a nice feature request, but I wonder if bumping maxRetries higher and using a [dynamic retry policy with backoff](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#dynamic-retry-with-backoff) would be better? Or, if that job is super critical, would it have been better to have just requested a non-preemptible machine in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am currently using exponential backoff with maxRetries set to 8 and the longest sleep duration ~2h. If this feature is not supported, then probably switching to non-preemptible machines for critical tasks is the only way to go. Thanks.